# RewriteBase in Drupal not working

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, mod-rewrite

I just developed Drupal based website, instead of old one "custom" made.

Problem I'm facing is that root of website is not apache root. It is in directory:

```
/public_html/mydomain/htdocs/
```

Due to all of that, my links now looks like:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/mydomain/htdocs/php
http://www.mydomain.com/mydomain/htdocs/java
http://www.mydomain.com/mydomain/htdocs/jquery
```

Tried to change directive in Drupal's .htaccess file, with:

```
RewriteBase /mysite/htdocs
```

... but that made no changes to links.

Also, with previous website all links worked fine...

Can you tell me how to fix this directive.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

RewriteBase is not used for that purpose. You need to be editing the `virtual host` or vhost file. Find the vhost file in your apache configuration and change the `DocumentRoot` to your folder `/public_html/mydmian/htdocs/` and just comment-out rewritebase.

RewriteBase is if your site is in a sub-folder of a "document root." What you have IS the document root.

Comment: my site is not into document root. also, my drupal site is hosted on public web service, i can not edit apache configuration file

Comment: I don't know how you're shared hosting is configured but `htdocs` should be a root directory, it should never be in the path. htdocs is probably already configured, in which case, just remove the rewriteBase completely.